# angularjs app to redirect after login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

Currently, when the users logs in, the login page does't redirect to the homepage.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myapp').service('auth', function auth($http, API_URL, authToken, $state, $window, $q) {
  function authSuccessful(res) {
    authToken.setToken(res.token);
    $state.go('main');
  }

  this.login = function (email, password) {
    return $http.post(API_URL + 'login', {
      email: email,
      password: password
    }).success(authSuccessful);
  }

  this.register = function (email, password) {
    return $http.post(API_URL + 'register', {
      email: email,
      password: password
    }).success(authSuccessful);
  }
```

However, I have set my `$state.go` to redirect to main. Where is the problem? why is it not redirecting?

### annex

here is my login.js controller, how it looks:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, alert, auth, $auth) {

  $scope.submit = function () {
    $auth.login({
      email: $scope.email,
      password: $scope.password
    })
      .then(function(res) {
        var message = 'Thanks for coming back ' + res.data.user.email + '!';
        if (!res.data.user.active)
          message = 'Just a reminder, please activate your account soon :)';

        alert('success', 'Welcome', message);
      })
      .catch(handleError);
  }
  // i forgot to include this error handler in my code:
  function handleError(err) {
    alert('warning', 'oops there is a problem!', err.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: Try to write  $state.go('main') in your controller  see if it works

Comment: @georgeawg .success() only gets called on success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an async action, angular doesn't know when the action finishes and thus when to update the $scope. For this to work you'll need to manually call $scope.apply(), but since you don't have access to the $scope in your service, you need to move the redirection logic (i.e. `$state.go('main')`) inside a controller, and call it like this:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, auth, $state) {

 function redirect(res) {
    $state.go('main');

    // manually update the scope
    $scope.$apply();
  }

  auth.login(email, password)
      .success(redirect);
});
```

**EDIT:** Integrate with the given controller

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, alert, auth, $auth) {

    $scope.submit = function () {
        $auth.login({
          email: $scope.email,
          password: $scope.password
        })
            .then(function(res) {
              var message = 'Thanks for coming back ' + res.data.user.email + '!';
              if (!res.data.user.active) {
                message = 'Just a reminder, please activate your account soon :)';
              }

              alert('success', 'Welcome', message);

              return null;
            })
            .then(function() {
              $state.go('main');

              // manually update the scope
              $scope.$apply();
            })
            // google replacement of the above commented out code bit
            .catch(handleError);
      }
    });
```

**EDIT 2**: Use $timeout instead of $scope.$apply so you don't get $digest error.

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, alert, auth, $auth, $timeout) {

    ...
    .then(function() {
      // $timeout calls $scope.$apply() by default, 
      // but it does it in a safely manner - never throws a '$digest already in progress' exception 
      $timeout(function() {
         $state.go('main');
      });
    })
    ...
```

Comment: could you please help me to integrate it into my login controller, that i included in the question after update. thanks

Comment: sure, what is the alert('success', ...) returning? Is it a promise or is it the default js alert dialog?

Comment: it is just an alert message to say that the user has logged in.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If it doesn't work than there's some other issue. Can be with defining the state itself, or an exception being thrown.

Comment: thanks, it is redirecting to the homepage, however, I updated my code, because i forgot to include my own error handler. Now, I get redirected to homepage, but the error message is "oops there is a problem! [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$rootScope/inprog?p=%24digest

is it because I haven't remove the old authSuccessful function from the login.js?

Comment: yes, that's the peril of using $scope.$apply(). A better way is to use $timeout. I'll update

Comment: working like a charm, however, $state needed to be included in the function. thanks a lot!

Comment: awesome, glad to help!